# Is an instance of object (but not a subclass) guaranteed to compare unequal to any other object?

Tags: python

Apologies if this is a dupe. (I couldn't find it but I'm not very good with google.)

I just stumbled over some code where they use

```
x = object()
```

in a place where they probably want `x` to compare not equal to anyhing that's already there. Is that guaranteed by the language?

Comment: You can use `is` to check reference equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nothing** is guaranteed. You can make anything equals to anything else by implementing `__eq__`.

Unless you know what `x` is, nothing is guaranteed and nothing can be assumed.

For example:

```
class A:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

print(A() == object())
# True
```

And the contrary:

```
class A:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

print(A() == object())
# False
```

Comment: That's awkward. Just checked what happens if I let your two classes face off against each other. It seems the left one wins in that case. Is there no way to be safe from such wanton vandalism?

Comment: @PaulPanzer If the "left" object doesn't implement `__eq__` (ie `class A: pass`) than Python will use the "right" object's `__eq__`. And no, there is not much you can do against it, other than using custom methods for comparison instead of `==` (which in turn could be monkey patched from outside the class, but that's a whole different story)

Answer (score 5):

If you compare it by using `x == other_object`, then this *might* return `True`. Since a custom class can override the `__eq__` function, and make it for instance equal to *every* other object.

But we can use `is` to check whether the two operands refer to the *same* object. So we can for instance use it like:

```
dummy = object()
lookup = somedict.get(somekey, dummy):
if lookup is dummy:
    # we did *not* find the key in the dictionary
    pass
else:
    pass
```

Since we just created the `dummy` object, there is no way that object can be in the `somedict` (unless it is of course something like `locals()`), so as a result we know for sure that if we find the key in the dictionary, then it will *not* return `dummy`. So we can use `is` safely to determine that.

Comment: Thanks! Two perfectly good and helpful answers. This time I'll have to accept @DeepSpace's since they apparently were 6 seconds quicker...